# How to sprout quinoa (and other grains) safely

Tags: quinoa, grains, sprouting

I've recently begun sprouting my own grains but I've found (no matter the method I use) that they tend to be too...crunchy? My boyfriend described my last batch of black quinoa tasting like it had some sort of "husk" or "shell" on it that made the flavor and texture less desirable.

I make sure to rinse the quinao thoroughly to avoid getting a bitter or soapy result at the end (rinsing at least three times). And rinse at least 2-3 times a day to make sure to avoid mold growth.

So far I have tried the following methods, plus some (note: I do not have a sprouter, I use a large mason jar):

1. [WikiHow](http://instructions.wikihow.com/Sprout-Quinoa) with a short rinse/soak period
2. [Ehow](http://www.ehow.com/how_4430690_sprout-quinoa.html) with a longer soak and a 2-3 times a day rinse
3. [Power of Food](http://www.poweroffood.com/how-to-sprout-quinoa-with-ease/) with a upside down container to make sure everything is drained off thoroughly

I also have used paper towel, light cloths and cheese cloths as covers depending on which method and what it describes.

It seems consistently I am getting a little better each time, but they are still a little hard. Is it my water temperature (I've used tap and make sure not to make it too hot or too cold).

Any suggestions or tried and true methods to get a good result with grain sprouting?

Comment: How many days? how far developed? maybe go until cotelydons go green (first leaf-like thing)

Comment: @PatSommer It depends on which method I'm using. I've gone upward to three and four days.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated above that you have used every possible method, i use simple method for grain sprouting. First i wash grain properly to remove dust and then soak them in normal temperature water for at least time mentioned in recipe.The first step in preparing quinoa is to remove the saponins, a process that requires soaking the grain in water for a few hours, then changing the water and re-soaking, or rinsing it in ample. So, continuously changing water after ever 3 hrs to keep them fresh. Then followed by your usual sprouting method. But for sure there must be the problem with the quality of grain batch which may be due to fertilizing,soil or any other reason. You better purchase from some good quality grains then follow the usual procedure of sprouting. 
It happens sometimes, i had been through same once but till that stock lasts in my kitchen. There after i went to have good quality grains and issue resolved. Hope it would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you  can change how a grain sprouts.  It is going to sprout, how it sprouts.  If you do not like it, try another seed source or another seed altogether.  There are so many plants that have many varieties.  Maybe you had a different variety last time or a different seed altogether.  One issue may be that the seeds are not for sprouting.   I cannot find my notes on sprouting but this looked informative.

http://learningstore.uwex.edu/assets/pdfs/A3385.PDF

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you perhaps summarize what you thought was informative about the link with respect to the question? We like to have complete answers here, and provide links for further reading, to make our site more useful for readers.

Answer (score 0):

If your grains seem too firm, you could try letting the sprouts develop further. The longer they have to sprout, the more of the carbohydrates (which can be crunchy) will be used up by the developing plant. If you are exclusively sprouting grains though, some of the crunch may be normal. A lot of grains have a husk or similar outer layer that will never quite go away with sprouting (but may soften a bit more if kept moist longer).